# App Engine Deployment Issue with Node.js 18 Runtime

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am experiencing a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) App Engine deployment issue with the nodejs18 runtime. With the [recent release](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/release-notes), the App Engine seems to be running the build command from the script and installing development dependencies, which contradicts the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies) stating that only the packages listed in the dependencies section should be installed, not the development ones.

Upon closely examining the build logs, we discovered a difference in the command after the recent release:

Before the release, the following command was being executed:

```
npm install
```

However, now the App Engine is running the following command, which also installs development dependencies:

```
npm ci
```

To circumvent the issue of the build command being triggered, we added `gcp-build: ""` to the `package.json` file to prevent it from looking at the regular build command.

I wish GCP had conducted more thorough testing before implementing these changes.

Comment: Thanks. Big breaking change indeed. Note this only applies to "standard" app engine, not "flexible"